# Possible bug in httpclient when using the blob data type

Tags: angular

After I started using the Angular 17 version and recommending the use of withFetch, the GET method that searches for BLOB stopped working.
If you don't use withFetch, the PDF opens normally within my template's iframe.
Note: No errors are displayed during compilation or at run time. The PDF is displayed with faulty content, showing strange texts and characters.
What's wrong in the code below? Could it be a bug?

app.config.ts

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
    providers: [
        provideRouter(routes),
        provideHttpClient(
            withInterceptorsFromDi(),
            withFetch()
        ),   
...
}
```

services.ts

```
public downloadDiagrammedPdf(sumarioId: number, nomeDoDiagramaPDF: string): Observable<HttpEvent<Blob>> {
    return this.http.request(
      new HttpRequest('GET', `${this.apiDownloadPdfUrl}?sumarioId=${sumarioId}&nomeDoDiagramaPDF=${nomeDoDiagramaPDF}`, null, {
        reportProgress: true,
        responseType: 'blob',
      })
    );
  }
```

showPdf.componente.ts

```
downloadFile(sumarioId: number, nomeDoDiagramaPDF: string): void {
    this.serviceUpDown.downloadDiagrammedPdf(sumarioId, nomeDoDiagramaPDF).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        switch (data.type) {
          case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
            break;
          case HttpEventType.Response:
            //this.downloadStatus.emit({ status: ProgressStatusEnum.COMPLETE });
            const file = new Blob([data.body as BlobPart], {
              type: data.body?.type,
            });
            this.createPdfFromBlob(file);
            break;
        }
      },
      error: (err) => {
        //this.downloadStatus.emit({ status: ProgressStatusEnum.ERROR });
        if (err.status == 404) {
          this.router.navigate(['app-error-page']);
        }
        else
          console.log(err);

      },
      complete: () => { }
    });
  }

  createPdfFromBlob(file: Blob) {
    this.pdfSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
  }
```

version:

```
{
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.0.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.1.2",
    "@material/icon-button": "^15.0.0-canary.684e33d25.0",
    "angular-imask": "^7.1.3",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^17.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a bug, the mime type is missing in the blob.

Until a fix lands, you can workaround this issue by setting the `type` yourself on the blob !

```
  createPdfFromBlob(file: Blob) {
    file = file.slice(0, file.size, "application/pdf")
    this.pdfSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
  }
```

PR to track: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/52840

Comment: It worked! So it's really a bug. I should have noticed that the Blob object is missing a mime type.
Do you have an estimate of when the fix will be released?
So, while the correction doesn't come, I have to adopt this palliative correction in other areas of the code to open other types of files.

Comment: I hope to land this for the next release on wednesday.

Comment: FYI It's merged, expect a release on wednesday ! =)

Comment: i updated the version today and the problem still persists.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't updated @angular/core. Now it worked.